# Writing Generic Physics Vector Class

Tags: java, generics, physics

It's been difficult to Google for a solution, because I'm not interested in the vector data strucutre. I'm interested in the phytsics vector. I'm trying to create a generic class to wrap any number type for a Vector. This is my original `double` vector:

```
public class Vector2D {
    private double x, y;

    Vector2D (double x, double y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public static Vector2D random() {
        return new Vector2D(Math.random() * 2 - 1, Math.random() * 2 - 1);
    }

    public double magnitude(){
        return Math.sqrt(this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y);
    }

    public Vector2D add(Vector2D other) {
        return new Vector2D(this.x + other.x, this.y + other.y);
    }
    //etc...
}
```

However, I'm coming across some dificulites in porting this to a generic class. This is what I have so far:

```
public class Vector2D<T extends Number> {
    private T x, y;

    Vector2D (T x, T y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public static Vector2D random() {
        return new Vector2D(Math.random() * 2 - 1, Math.random() * 2 - 1);
    }

    public T magnitude(){
        //this gives an error: cannot cast from double to T
        return (T)Math.sqrt(this.x.doubleValue() * this.x.doubleValue() + this.y.doubleValue() * this.y.doubleValue());
    }
}
```

I'm stuck on `magnitude` and `random`. I'm really stumped. Any guidance as to how I can complete those methods?

Comment: Even if it compiles fine you will end up with code like `Vector2D<Integer> intVector = Vector2D.random();` but `random()` is filling values using `double` which can at best be boxed to `Double` which can't be cast to `Integer` which we require. I suspect that if creating such class only for numeric types was possible we would already have them in Java, but I may be wrong.

Comment: @Pshemo So any ideas on how to write the proposed class?

Comment: "*I suspect that if creating such class only for numeric types was possible we would already have them in Java*" so no, I don't think it is possible to create what you want. You may want to create separate methods for different datatypes like `randomInt` which will create `Vector2d<Integer>`, `randomDouble` for `Vector2d<Double>` and so on. But you still will need to solve problem with operations on vector like addition, subtraction, scaling, which will involve operating on values in vector, but `*` or `+` can't be used with `Number`.

Comment: why do you need to do this anyway? If you're concerned with memory space, use floats. If you specifically want another data type for ints, you'll have to make a different one. Since with generics you can only use wrapper classes and since Java doesn't support user value types (structs), you'll have to do what @Pshemo said. This isn't a problem in a language like C# though...